# How to plot geom_tile() with offset geom_text() labels indicated using arrows?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, geom-text, geom-tile

I can plot `geom_tile()`s with labels via `geom_text()` like so:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- structure(list(x = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 
                           3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), 
                     y = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
                     z = c("stuff", "not_stuff", "not_stuff", "not_stuff", "not_stuff", "stuff", 
                           "stuff", "not_stuff", "stuff", "stuff", "not_stuff", "stuff", 
                           "stuff", "not_stuff", "stuff", "not_stuff")), 
                class = "data.frame", 
                row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                     -16L))

plt <- ggplot2::ggplot(data = df, mapping = ggplot2::aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) + 
  ggplot2::geom_tile(height = ifelse(z == "stuff", 0.4, 0.1)) + 
  ggplot2::geom_text(ggplot2::aes(label = ifelse(z == "stuff", z, "")))

plt
```

[image: plt1]

But I'd like to have the labels offset from the tiles themselves with an arrow (curved or otherwise) like this instead:

[image: plt2]

(Apologies for the poor drawing.) I'd like to have the label for each tile shown with an arrow like that one example I've depicted in the figure above.

I'm not sure how to do this, and I wasn't really able to find an answer elsewhere.

Any help and/or pointers would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geom_label_repel` from the `ggrepel` package works well for this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) + 
  geom_tile(height = ifelse(z == "stuff", 0.4, 0.1)) + 
  geom_label_repel(
    aes(label = ifelse(z == "stuff", z, "")), 
    fill = NA, 
    nudge_y = 0.5
  )
```

[image]